# Best way to work out how to use this LCD screen without datasheet

Tags: i2c, datasheet, lcd

I found this LCD screen in an electrical waste bin, however after googling the board number and the controller on it I haven't been able to find any results. I can't for the life of me work out whats going on with the 14 pin connector but was hoping to use the 2 sets of I2C pins on the right and bottom of the board to interface with it. Is there a way for me to do that without a datasheet? and if so what format do I need to send the I2C message in?

[image: Back of the Screen]

Comment: Do you have a protocol/digital analyzer?

Comment: If you know nothing about the board or chips on it, there's no way you can communicate with it. The main interface seems to be th colourful cable on the left, the I2C looks like to be for programing the I2C EEPROM contents and the other for debugging.

Comment: It could be possible to identify the controller if you post a picture where the markings are readable.

Comment: This is a post that keeps coming back, unless you have all the details then bin it. Many others have asked similar questions, even “I bought this cheap on xyz site but it lacks documentation…”.

Comment: Was this LCD in a larger unit or product?  It seems kind of custom to me.